# Filling a sectioned RecyclerView using a SortedDictionary, ViewHolders under section not showing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.forms

I'm currently trying to figure out how to create a list of events, of which the events are sectioned by DateTime. My solution is based on [thetonrifles](https://github.com/thetonrifles/stackoverflow/tree/so-34848401/app/src/main/java/com/thetonrifles/stackoverflow)'s solution in Java, but a for loop was used to rebuild his hashmap back into a one-dimensional `ArrayList<ListItem>`. In my "solution" I'm trying to completely omit this and the need for a custom `ListItem` class or its children as I think they are completely unnecessary. Having an unnecessary for-loop might slow things down.

I have been able to get the iteration through events per `DateTime` key going, but when I try manually firing `OnCreateViewHolder()` and `OnBindViewHolder()` using the `CreateViewHolder()` and `BindViewHolder()` functions, the Recyclerview is not updated with new `EventViewHolder`s.

Below is my extension of the `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
public class EventsRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter {
    public SortedDictionary<DateTime, List<Event>> EventDictionary { get; set; }
    private const int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private const int TYPE_EVENT = 1;
    ViewGroup viewGroupHelper;

    public override int ItemCount => this.EventDictionary.Count;

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
        View itemView;
        viewGroupHelper = parent;
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            itemView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_eventlist_header, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
        }
        itemView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_eventlist_event, parent, false);
        return new EventViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder is EventViewHolder) {
            EventViewHolder eViewHolder = holder as EventViewHolder;
            eViewHolder.EventTitle.Text = "Test";
            return;
        }
        HeaderViewHolder hViewHolder = holder as HeaderViewHolder;
        DateTime eventStartGroup = EventDictionary.Keys.ElementAt(position);
        hViewHolder.EventStartGroup.Text = (DateTime.Today == eventStartGroup) ? "Today" : eventStartGroup.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
        List<Event> eventsUnderDate = EventDictionary.Values.ElementAt(position);
        FillEventsUnderDate(viewGroupHelper, position, eventsUnderDate);
    }

    private void FillEventsUnderDate(ViewGroup parent, int position, List<Event> events) {
        foreach (Event @event in events) {
            EventViewHolder holder = CreateViewHolder(parent, TYPE_EVENT) as EventViewHolder;
            BindViewHolder(holder, position++);
        }
    }

    private class HeaderViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView EventStartGroup { get; set; }
        public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView) {
            EventStartGroup = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.eventlist_header);
        }
    }

    private class EventViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView EventTitle { get; set; }
        public EventViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView) {
            EventTitle = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.eventlist_event);
        }
    }
}
```

There're 2 possible causes:

1. I'm passing an incorrect position to `BindViewHolder()` (wild guess but established case)
2. I'm simply forgetting something inside the event listeners which would cause the `ViewHolder` to not show itself

Now this might get close to an XY-Problem. Building a solution based on [thetonrifles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2371579/thetonrifles)'s code works fine using nice looking `CardView`s and such, but I'd like to know what's missing in my code that causes the absence of my `EventViewHolder`s that should hold the respective events. Omitting the extra for-loop is reasonable and should be possible, correct?

**EDIT**

Because of the last edit, it has been made even less clear what I'm trying to ask. It's not "How do I create a list of events, of which the events are sectioned by `DateTime`?", but rather "Why are my `EventViewHolders` under the date-section not showing?". I understood why the question in some cases had to be made "more concise", but editing the first sentence must have confused at least one person already.

This is what my RecyclerView currently looks like. It displays the HeaderViewHolders, but not the EventViewHolders. The absence of the EventViewHolder is what I need help with in this case:

[image: EventViewHolder not showing]

Comment: You know, recyclerview calls `OnCreateViewHolder` once to create a viewholder and then every time it wants to view the item it sends the viewholder to `OnBindViewHolder`. So `FillEventsUnderDate` doesn't do anything. It creates a viewholder but since it is not used by the recyclerview nothing happens. I didn't understand your question completely but I think you could try `NotifyItemChanged`.

Comment: No, I think you're steering me in the right direction here. I call this in the if statement of `OnBindViewHolder()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, you may try it.

Comment: I have not tried `NotifyItemChanged()` yet. I assumed that `OnBindViewHolder()` would be responsible for displaying the View in the RecyclerView. By calling `BindViewHolder()`, `OnBindViewHolder` is called. Only thing that's different is when `holder is EventViewHolder`, I change the text of the TextView and the rest would handle itself, as that seems to be what happens with the HeaderViewHolder. There's no problem with displaying the headers. I'll upload a picture of what the list looks like at the moment and put it in the edit.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar Calling `NotifyItemChanged()` or `NotifyItemInserted()` wherever in the adapter throws `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException`. "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling..."

Comment: yes, you shouldn't call it for example in `OnBindViewHolder`. this method can update your items after they are created.

Comment: I read your code again and the java code that you have found for your question. that java code is completely correct and if you think it has unnecessary loops you should work on that part not the other parts.

your code has other problems for example your `Count` is not correct. recyclerview get items based on the count that you return.  I think it will be a good idea if you study recyclerview mechanism deeply.

Answer (score 0):

From your codes, you are filling the data through `FillEventsUnderDate`, and inside this method, you are filling the data by calling `CreateViewHolder` and `BindViewHolder`. And yes, it did generate an `EventViewHolder` eventually:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    ...
    FillEventsUnderDate(viewGroupHelper, position, eventsUnderDate);
}

private void FillEventsUnderDate(ViewGroup parent, int position, List<Event> events)
{   
    foreach (Event @event in events)
    {
        //this holder is never used by RecyclerView
        EventViewHolder holder = CreateViewHolder(parent, TYPE_EVENT) as EventViewHolder;
        BindViewHolder(holder, position++);
    }
}
```

But then what? **The generated `EventViewHolder` was never used by the `RecyclerView`**.

If you refer to the [source codes of RecyclerView(lines:1301-1309)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/247185b98675b09c5e98c87448dd24aef4dffc9d/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#1301), the `CreateViewHolder` is called by the adapter and it creates a holder that is consumed by the `RecyclerView`. So, as it is a wrong direction of using `RecyclerView`, I don't have any solution regarding the question. I can only suggest trying some other way to have an solution to the requirement.